# PHP SQL update failed

Tags: php, sql

In database `login` replace `x` with `y` in column `z` where `username=$usr`.

That's what I'm trying to create (at least I hope you understand what I mean).

My code, right now is:

```
<?php
session_start();
$servernaam = "server";
$susr = "user";
$spswd = "password";
$sdbnaam = "database name";
$usr = $_SESSION['usr'];
$qa = "1";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servernaam, $susr, $spswd, $sdbnaam);
$sql = "UPDATE login SET qa='$qa' WHERE username=$usr";
header("Location: Page_1.php");
?>
```

**Question**:

In the database, nothing changes. The cell I want to change stays at it's previous value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so..what's wrong?did you have a question?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: @vkp Sorry, I compleatle forgot to mention it..
In the database nothing changes. The cell I want to change stayes at it's previous statement...

Comment: Also `Login` is a reserved word

Comment: @sami My database is calles login, should I give it a different name to let it work?

Comment: @Niels Your Table name is `Login` not the db, and yes you should change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking someone who had a lot of knowlage of php and sql I've got the awnser! 
This:

```
$sql = "UPDATE login SET qa='$qa' WHERE username=$usr";
```

should have been 
This:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `login` SET `qa`='$qa' WHERE `username`='$usr'";
```

And I didn't add 
This:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

wich actually runs the sql script.